# Maven project coming in folder structure and not as packages

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, protocol-buffers, package

I just imported a Maven project in eclipse using : Import > Maven > Existing Maven Projects, but in eclipse it comes as a folder structure and not in a package structure, which means the project is not building also.

Please tell me how to fix it.
[image]

i.e., in the above image under edmkt project src > main > google and so on.. folders are shown(it has .proto files and not .java files), and under edtmkt-all-service, src/main/java package is shown.

Comment: You're going to have to be much more specific.  I have no idea what you mean by "comes as a folder structure and not in a package structure".  Perhaps a screenshot from the Package Explorer would help illustrate what you're talking about?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr Please look at the above screenshot.

Comment: It might help to know what errors you're seeing.

Comment: An Ant BuildException has occured: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "..\protobuf\protoc.2.5.0" This is the error in pom.xml @DavidM.Karr

Comment: Well, then, it looks like you need help from a protocol buffer community.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this issue by below steps:

Right click the Maven Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
In Order and Export tab, you can see the message like '2 build path entries are missing'
Now select 'JRE System Library' and 'Maven Dependencies' checkbox
Click OK
Now you can see below in all type of Explorers (Package or Project or Navigator)

src/main/java

src/main/resources

src/test/java